# How to fix the Apple Mach-O Linker Error

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

In my project I need to implement the candle stick chart this link (https://github.com/i-schuetz/SwiftCharts) help me to implement it. It's work fine for me in Xcode Version 8.2.1 (8C1002) but in Xcode Version 8.3 beta (8W109m) I'm getting error. Here with I have attached the screenshot for my error. struggling in that last two days. Hoe to solve this issue. Thanks in Advance [Apple Mach-O Linker Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmI7A.png)

Comment: you need to add necessary framework to project . then build again

Comment: Hi... In this example they didn't add any framework. how can I add it now for Xcode Version 8.3 beta (8W109m). where can I found the famework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem has different solutions , one of them is to set **Enable Bitcode** to **No** . [image: See her]
( By the way , this may not the solution for you  but there is a possibility . Just try )

Comment: Sorry about that , it worked for me so i shared @Devi